# Dropline menus -- seperators between children only?

Tags: functions, menus

I'm working on a custom dropline menu using wp_nav_menu.

Using `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'after' => '|' ) );`, I can put separators after every item. However, I'm only wanting them after the child items in the sub-menu.

Is there any way I can be more specific about which items have separators, such that only the non-parent items are separated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a purely CSS-based solution, using the `:after` pseudo-element? e.g.

```
#nav li li a:after {
    content: '|';
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about using the "content" attribute. That's totally what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Walker class which wordpress uses for wp_nav_menu to style your menu in your way....

Here is an example...

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Answer (score 0):

For a similar project, I used a single line of jQuery to selectively add spacers:

```
jQuery('ul#menu-main-menu-1 li.menu-item-267, ul#menu-main-menu-1 li.menu-item-265').append(' | ');
```

Leaving question open in hopes that somebody has a more elegant solution than this...